# Split cell values into multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel with multiple dates in a single cell separated by comma as follows:

```
Name         Work Days  
Person 1     2,3,5  
Person 2     1,2  
Person 3     5  
Person 4     1,2,3,6,7
```

Now I need to make an X mark against only the working days so that my output looks as follows:

```
Name         Work Days    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
Person 1     2,3,5             X    X         X
Person 2     1,2          X    X
Person 3     5                                X
Person 4     1,2,3,6,7    X    X    X              X    X
```

Please note that the dates in the table header does not need to be dynamically populated as they are fixed. I just need to put the X mark against the corresponding columns. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you attempted or considered?

Comment: You can do with formula as well. VBA is not required. But as indicated by @AndyG you need to show us your efforts!

Comment: Hint (https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-cells-contain-either-x-or-y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you wanted some VBA in the solution, enter this UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function IsIn(big As String, little As Variant) As String
    IsIn = ""
    If InStr(big, CStr(little)) > 0 Then
        IsIn = "X"
    End If
End Function
```

Then in **C2** enter:

```
=isin($B2,C$1)
```

copy this both across and downward:

[image]

**NOTE:**

- you can use a worksheet formula rather than a UDF()
- this works for values like 1 through 7 *(days of week)*; not so well for values like 1 through 31 *(days of month)*

Comment: Very good.  I was working on something a lot more heavyweight.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Gary's Student answer but as I was in the middle of writing mine, I thought I'd dump it here anyhow.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestParseData()
    Dim vReport As Variant
    vReport = ParseData(MockData)

End Sub

Function MockData() As Variant

    Dim vData As Variant
    ReDim vData(1 To 4, 1 To 2)
    vData(1, 1) = "Person 1"
    vData(2, 1) = "Person 2"
    vData(3, 1) = "Person 3"
    vData(4, 1) = "Person 4"

    vData(1, 2) = "2,3,5"
    vData(2, 2) = "1,2"
    vData(3, 2) = "5"
    vData(4, 2) = "1,2,3,6,7"

    MockData = vData



End Function

Function ParseData(ByVal vData As Variant) As Variant

    '* start of pre-conditions
    On Error Resume Next
    '* test for two dimension array like off a sheet range
    Dim vRows As Variant, vColumns As Variant
    vRows = UBound(vData, 1) - LBound(vData, 1) + 1
    vColumns = UBound(vData, 2) - LBound(vData, 2) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsEmpty(vRows) Or IsEmpty(vColumns) Then Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "#Please supply a 2d array from a sheet range with two columns!"
    If vColumns <> 2 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "#Please supply a 2d array from a sheet range with two columns!"
    '* end of pre-conditions

    ReDim dicPersonSchedule(LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)) As Scripting.Dictionary

    '* STEP 1 , load up all work days in each person's dictionary
    '*     and find Min and Max of workdays to define range
    Dim lPersonLoop As Long
    Dim lMax As Long: lMax = -1
    Dim lMin As Long: lMin = 2 ^ 30
    For lPersonLoop = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
        Set dicPersonSchedule(lPersonLoop) = New Scripting.Dictionary

        Dim vWorkDaysSplit As Variant
        vWorkDaysSplit = Split(vData(lPersonLoop, 2), ",")

        Dim vWorkDaysSplitLoop As Variant
        For Each vWorkDaysSplitLoop In vWorkDaysSplit
            If Not IsNumeric(vWorkDaysSplitLoop) Then Err.Raise "#Bad data, expecting commas and numbers!"

            If vWorkDaysSplitLoop < lMin Then lMin = vWorkDaysSplitLoop
            If vWorkDaysSplitLoop > lMax Then lMax = vWorkDaysSplitLoop
            dicPersonSchedule(lPersonLoop).add vWorkDaysSplitLoop, 0
        Next
    Next lPersonLoop

    '*STEP 2 - load the report
    ReDim vReturn(LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1), lMin To lMax)

    For lPersonLoop = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
        For Each vWorkDaysSplitLoop In dicPersonSchedule(lPersonLoop).Keys
            vReturn(lPersonLoop, vWorkDaysSplitLoop) = "X"
        Next

    Next lPersonLoop

    ParseData = vReturn



End Function
```